# IF Statement Formatting, highlighting row range

Tags: excel, vba

Hello again the last time I posted a question it was resolved quite quickly.

Essentially what I am trying to do is if a row in column r says Project Complete then I want it to grey out the row from column D:BM

I was playing around with a few things but it doesn’t want to work.

The column r is also a vlookup formula to another workbook, not sure if that makes a difference.

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("R10:R1000")

For Each cell In rng

If cell.Value = "Project Complete" Then
Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row & ":BM" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Can't you use conditional formatting?

Comment: Change `ActiveCell.Row ` to `cell.row`

Comment: Also Combine the `Range("D"...` and `With..` lines like this: `With Range("D" & cell.Row & ":BM" & cell.Row)` to avoid using the `.Select`.  it only slows done the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the range without selection:

```
Sub OhYa()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Range("R10:R1000")

    For Each c In rng.Cells

        If c = "Project Complete" Then

            With Range("D" & c.Row & ":BM" & c.Row).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```